# Make EF use local database in App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using POCO approach on all my projects using Entity Framework. It's all good but I have one problem: It is creating database on my SQL Express, instead I want it to store my database in *.mdf file in App_Data folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set an appropriate connection string in Web.config that makes use of the [AttachDBFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) keyword.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyContextClassName"
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdf;User Instance=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: But the thing is that database is not created in my App_Data folder. It's created straight in SQLEXPRESS

Comment: @Stanislav Did you try the answer? "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|..." will create the database file inside of App_Data.

Comment: I tried and it showed me `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` when I did `update-database -f -v`.

Comment: @Stanislav Do you have any additional information? Does `$Errors[0].Exception.InnerException.ToString()` tell your more?

Comment: As it happends I upgraded to Win8 and now I don't even have SQLEXPRESS installed. Now it does what it is suppose to do - storing everything in file w/o even using database server.

Comment: @Stanislav Glad it is fixed. You are now using LocalDB -- the evolution of SQL Express User Instances.